# Force_legacy_cardinality_estimation hint questions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

1. Does the force_legacy_cardinality_estimation hint change cardinality for the whole query (or stored procedure) or just the section of code it's applied to? (For example, if there are multiple SELECT statements in a Stored Procedure but the hint is only on one of the SELECT statements.)
2. Can you use the hint in views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The force_legacy_cardinality_estimation hint changes cardinality for a particular statement it is applied to, not for the whole batch or an object (SP, trigger, UDF and so on).
2. No, you can't, because the SELECT clauses in a view definition cannot include the OPTION clause.